# Возможно ли в регулярном выражении инвертировать выборку?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть исходная строка `abcdef` в ней найти символы `cd` потом инвертировать выборку этих символов в исходной строке и в результате получить строку `abef` или массив с элементами в которых хранятся значения `ab` и `ef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов - инвертировать класс символов и искать все вхождения этого регулярного выражения

```
/[^cd]+/
```

Comment: работает, то что нужно, благодарю